# Ios 6 drawing app keeps stretching after strokes are made

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

Im currently making a drawing app, which I'm using a story board so i can implement a game with it was well. The drawingViewController's UIimageViewer only takes up about 3/4s of the screen, because the other 1/4 is used to keep buttons on and a sentence. However, every time I draw a line the image then gets stretched along the y-axis. My question is is there anything I can do to make it no longer stretch at all. Or would it be better if i make the UIimageViewer take up the whole screen and put the buttons over the top of that? I will also need to add a label and text box over the top of the UIimageview? Im pretty new with programming on iOS 6 so any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#import "DrawViewController.h"

@interface DrawViewController ()

@end

@implementation DrawViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    red = 0.0/255.0;
    green = 0.0/255.0;
    blue = 0.0/255.0;
    brush = 10.0;
    opacity = 1.0;

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)pencilPressed:(id)sender {
    UIButton * PressedButton = (UIButton*)sender;

    switch(PressedButton.tag)
    {
        case 0:
            red = 0.0/255.0;
            green = 0.0/255.0;
            blue = 0.0/255.0;
            break;
        case 1:
            red = 105.0/255.0;
            green = 105.0/255.0;
            blue = 105.0/255.0;
            break;
        case 2:
            red = 255.0/255.0;
            green = 0.0/255.0;
            blue = 0.0/255.0;
            break;
        case 3:
            red = 0.0/255.0;
            green = 0.0/255.0;
            blue = 255.0/255.0;
            break;
        case 4:
            red = 102.0/255.0;
            green = 204.0/255.0;
            blue = 0.0/255.0;
            break;
        case 5:
            red = 102.0/255.0;
            green = 255.0/255.0;
            blue = 0.0/255.0;
            break;
        case 6:
            red = 51.0/255.0;
            green = 204.0/255.0;
            blue = 255.0/255.0;
            break;
        case 7:
            red = 160.0/255.0;
            green = 82.0/255.0;
            blue = 45.0/255.0;
            break;
        case 8:
            red = 255.0/255.0;
            green = 102.0/255.0;
            blue = 0.0/255.0;
            break;
        case 9:
            red = 255.0/255.0;
            green = 255.0/255.0;
            blue = 0.0/255.0;
            break;
    }



}

- (IBAction)eraserPressed:(id)sender {

    red = 255.0/255.0;
    green = 255.0/255.0;
    blue = 255.0/255.0;
    opacity = 1.0;
}
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    mouseSwiped = NO;
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    lastPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    mouseSwiped = YES;
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
    [self.tempDrawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
    CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), brush );
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), red, green, blue, 1.0);
    CGContextSetBlendMode(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),kCGBlendModeNormal);

    CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    self.tempDrawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    [self.tempDrawImage setAlpha:opacity];
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    lastPoint = currentPoint;
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    if(!mouseSwiped) {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
        [self.tempDrawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
        CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
        CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), brush);
        CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), red, green, blue, opacity);
        CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
        CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
        CGContextFlush(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
        self.tempDrawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    }

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.mainImage.frame.size);
    [self.mainImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height) blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0];
    [self.tempDrawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height) blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:opacity];
    self.mainImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    self.tempDrawImage.image = nil;
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}
@end
```

Comment: Add some code to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that Imageview & image on that imageview both are of same size.

Comment: they are the same size, but it still stretches when anything is drawn to the ImageView

Comment: I fixed it, The view controller must not like it if the UIImageView is smaller than the controller itself. I made it the same size as the Controller and then added the buttons and labels to the top of the UIImageView. Now the canvas doesn't stretch when drawing. Thanks for the feedback and the resizing idea